# AbsorbingEffectError running PanelOLS regression with Python

Tags: regression, python, linear-model, panel-data

My dataframe looks something like that:

```
df.head()
                          x         y
id          day     
000001      2020-01-31  0.0 13.058878
            2020-02-03  0.0 13.173556
            2020-02-04  0.0 13.196818
            2020-02-05  0.0 11.838893
            2020-02-07  0.0 12.508497
```

and I'd like to run a fixed effects regression of x on y. This is my code:

```
dv = df.y
iv = sm2.add_constant(df[['x']])
fe_mod = PanelOLS(dv, iv, entity_effects=True)
fe_res = fe_mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
print(fe_res)
```

Unfortunately I receive an error message, which I don't understand:

```
AbsorbingEffectError: 
The model cannot be estimated. The included effects have fully absorbed
one or more of the variables. This occurs when one or more of the dependent
variable is perfectly explained using the effects included in the model.
```

The correlation between x and y is -0.354465. x is coded as 1 if an event occurs and 0 if it doesn't.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507204/how-to-fix-the-absorbing-effect-error-when-trying-to-include-fixed-effects-in-th) but it didn't receive an answer for over a year.

I don't understand why the "included effects have fully absorbed one or more of the variables". Is it because x does not change over time and therefore causes trouble with the FE?